# Why is it necessary to unregister the OnPreferenceChangeListener?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, listener

I have been following some tutorials and it says that you must unregister the `OnPreferenceChangeListener`.
Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's take a look at how registration is done.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

We can see that `SharedPreferences` is a global object because `getApplicationContext()` returns **single/static/global** application object of the current process. Now, here are 2 reasons why you should unregister `OnPreferenceChangeListener`:

1. Since `SharedPreferences` contains a list of listeners, if you wanted to listen for same event in different place, first listener (one that wasn't unregistered) would be invoked.
2. When you unregister a listener, GC will clean it up. Imagine you repeatedly open and close an activity which creates and registers one listener object, then a bunch of instances of the same listener is created (and you need only one). Memory leak will eventually happen.

Note: I think this explanation is good enough, but this answer is open for edits.